# 4g usb 551l will not connect linus 13.04

Tags: networking, broadband

Ihave a hp pavilion dv7 dual operating systems, windows and linux.I Connect with 4g verison usb 551l modem.It Works on windows but not on linux.The modem has linux driver installed